# Need to solve a large linear equation in an interesting format

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

My equation is actually derived from a 3-D tensor.  I need to solve for $x$ in the following
$ (A_{mn}^{m'n'} \delta_p^{p'} + B_{mp}^{m'p'} \delta_n^{n'} + C_{np}^{n'p'} \delta_m^{m'}) x_{m'n'p'} = b_{mnp} $

The problem is that the full $N^3 * N^3$ matrix is too large to invert, so I'd like an iterative method for solving.  I've tried Jacobi and conjugate gradient descent -- no luck.
Additional facts: $A, B, C$ are Hermitian, and in fact of the form $M^{\dagger} M$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which is the range for every index? N?

Comment: Yes. And N can be relatively large -- probably not up to 100, but 50 might be plausible. So I can multiply by/invert A,B,C in reasonable time, but not the full matrix.

Comment: Please state the linear system using standard mathematical notation. In particular use the Kronecker product and the $\text{vec}$ operator. We need $\text{any}$ special properties of $A$, $B$, and $C$ as well as the right hand side, which could possibly be exploited. This includes their sparsity pattern.

Comment: Well, this _is_ pretty standard tensor notation.  But here goes: $\vec{x}, \vec{b} \in V_1 \times V_2 \times V_3$, $V_1 \approx V_2 \approx V_3$, $A \in End(V_1 \times V_2), B \in End(V_1 \times V_3), C \in End(V_2 \times V_3)$, $(A \otimes I_3 + B \otimes I_2 + C \otimes I_1) \vec{x} = \vec{b}$.  I've given you everything I have in regards to the structure and sparsity of $A,B,C$ and $\vec{b}$.  I believe $A,B,C$ are of full rank, but I don't have a proof of that.

Comment: If I understood correctly you have a smaller then $10^6×10^6$ system? This should still be fine with a direct solver. Did you try using UMFPACK, e.g. Matlab and SciPy use this solver. (IMO one of the best implementation of a direct solver). For the CG-Iteration - what kind of preconditioner did you use? And what exacty do you mean with "no luck" - no convergence, convergence to the wrong result, large computation time etc.

Comment: Really? Matrix inverters can handle a $10^6 \times 10^6$ system?  Wouldn't that require prohibitive memory and time?  As to the preconditioner -- I didn't, I used the most naive possible methods.  That's sort of what I was wondering, would a matrix of this form have a special preconditioner?  And results were no convergence -- intermediate values diverged rapidly.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say $A,B,C$ are of the form $M^{\dagger}M$, $M$ is not a square matrix; it has dimensions $N'\times N$, with $N' > N$. I just have the explicit factorization.